# Enabling HTTPS support on micronaut with Jetty not working as expected

Tags: kotlin, ssl, servlets, jetty, micronaut

I'm trying to enable HTTPS support for a micronaut application I have that *uses Jetty*.
You can find a stripped down version of the application at: https://github.com/galzetta/debug-micronaut-https

[The documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#https) states that it should be enough to specify the following properties:

```
micronaut.ssl.enabled=true
micronaut.ssl.buildSelfSigned=true
```

and the webserver should automatically serve https on port `8443` with a newly generated self-signed certificate.

Moreover [the documentation](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#dualProtocol) claims that if `micronaut.ssl.enabled=true` then it **wont** server HTTP by default, but you can enable dual protocol handling.

**Fact:** when I specify the above properties:

1. Micronaut does listen on port `8443` but `curl` and the browser give SSL protocol errors.
2. Micronaut keeps listening on port `8080` too even if I did not specify `micronaut.server.dualProtocol=true` and even if I explicitly set this to `false`

For reference this is what I get at startup:

```
 __  __ _                                  _   
|  \/  (_) ___ _ __ ___  _ __   __ _ _   _| |_ 
| |\/| | |/ __| '__/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | __|
| |  | | | (__| | | (_) | | | | (_| | |_| | |_ 
|_|  |_|_|\___|_|  \___/|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_|\__|
  Micronaut (v2.3.3)

11:02:02.804 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @510ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
11:02:02.854 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - jetty-9.4.32.v20200930; built: 2020-09-30T16:16:37.804Z; git: de97d26f7bd222a0e16831e353d702a7a422f711; jvm 14.0.1+7
11:02:02.927 [main] INFO  o.e.j.server.handler.ContextHandler - Started i.m.s.j.@5ebd56e9{/,null,AVAILABLE}
11:02:03.008 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@2bb7bd00{SSL, (ssl, http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8443}
11:02:03.009 [main] INFO  o.e.jetty.server.AbstractConnector - Started ServerConnector@662f5666{HTTP/1.1, (http/1.1)}{0.0.0.0:8080}
11:02:03.009 [main] INFO  org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server - Started @716ms
11:02:03.011 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 443ms. Server Running: https://127.0.1.1:8443/
```

This is the error I get trying to request the HTTPS application:

```
$ curl -vvv 'https://127.0.1.1:8443/verify'   
*   Trying 127.0.1.1:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.1.1 (127.0.1.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Request CERT (13):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I had a doubt thinking that maybe it was serving HTTP on port 8443 but it seems not:

```
$ curl -vvv 'http://127.0.1.1:8443/verify'  
*   Trying 127.0.1.1:8443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.1.1 (127.0.1.1) port 8443 (#0)
> GET /verify HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.1.1:8443
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed

* Closing connection 0
curl: (1) Received HTTP/0.9 when not allowed
```

The application for testing is written in Kotlin and is:

```kotlin
package com.example

import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut.build

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    build()
        .args(*args)
        .packages("com.example")
        .start()
}

@Controller
class Controller {
    @Get("/verify")
    fun verify(): String = "Working!"
}
```

The `pom.xml` is (reduced from the real one):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>server</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <jdk.version>11</jdk.version>
        <release.version>11</release.version>
        <micronaut.version>2.3.3</micronaut.version>
        <exec.mainClass>com.example.ApplicationKt</exec.mainClass>
        <kotlinVersion>1.4.10</kotlinVersion>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jcenter.bintray.com</id>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-http-server-jetty</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ========================================================================== -->
        <!-- Explicitly include jetty-servlet since we needed it at compile-time        -->
        <!-- Cause: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-servlet/issues/114  -->
        <!-- ========================================================================== -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.32.v20200930</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-reflect</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-kotlin-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-runtime</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micronaut.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>micronaut-kotlin-extension-functions</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>${jdk.version}</jvmTarget>
                    <compilerPlugins>
                        <plugin>all-open</plugin>
                    </compilerPlugins>
                    <pluginOptions>
                        <option>all-open:annotation=io.micronaut.aop.Around</option>
                    </pluginOptions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>kapt</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>kapt</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                            <annotationProcessorPaths>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                                <annotationProcessorPath>
                                    <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>micronaut-validation</artifactId>
                                    <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
                                </annotationProcessorPath>
                            </annotationProcessorPaths>
                            <annotationProcessorArgs>
                                <annotationProcessorArg>
                                    micronaut.processing.group=com.example
                                </annotationProcessorArg>
                                <annotationProcessorArg>
                                    micronaut.processing.module=server
                                </annotationProcessorArg>
                            </annotationProcessorArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-allopen</artifactId>
                        <version>${kotlinVersion}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <proc>none</proc>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-compile</id>
                        <phase>none</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>java-compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Note: the documentation for micronaut servlet doesn't say anything about HTTPS, in fact it just links to micronaut's documentation, which makes me think that everything should work by default. See: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-servlet/1.0.x/guide/#faq

---

**Note**: if I use Netty it *does* work as intended binding only on 8443:

```
 __  __ _                                  _   
|  \/  (_) ___ _ __ ___  _ __   __ _ _   _| |_ 
| |\/| | |/ __| '__/ _ \| '_ \ / _` | | | | __|
| |  | | | (__| | | (_) | | | | (_| | |_| | |_ 
|_|  |_|_|\___|_|  \___/|_| |_|\__,_|\__,_|\__|
  Micronaut (v2.3.3)

14:13:04.325 [main] INFO  io.micronaut.runtime.Micronaut - Startup completed in 1482ms. Server Running: https://0.0.0.0:8443
```

And the controller works:

```sh
$ curl -k https://localhost:8443/verify
Working!
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the request without validating the certificate ..

```
curl -k -vvv 'https://127.0.1.1:8443/verify'
```

If that works, then it means means your SSL/TLS layer is working, but likely not with a certificate that is signed against a known CA that curl and your browser recognize.  (The fact that you enabled `micronaut.ssl.buildSelfSigned=true` hints at this situation)

If you got this far, then at this point you need to focus on what's important to you when it comes to the certificates in the keystore, and how you intend to access the server.

General advice:

- Don't access the server with an IP (that breaks most SSL/TLS certificate validation)
- Don't access the server via localhost (that's not supported by browsers, and you cannot have a certificate for "localhost" anyway)
- If you want to avoid the warnings on the browser, and the `curl -k` requirement, then you need to have your certificate signed by a CA that both the browser and your curl recognize (using letsencrypt is a great option and is also free)
- Your certificate is tied to your hostname, if the hostname changes, so does your certificate (in most cases).

Comment: `curl -k` or `curl --insecure` does not change the error. I still get: `curl: (35) error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure`.
From the error I believe it breaks before sending the certificate, at the initial negotiation for ssl/tls protocol